# Matching plan text to HTML content

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to perform matching between plant text to HTML content and once matched found, I need to extract the matched HTML contents **(without changing the HTML content As I need the exactly same HTML content)** , I am able to match in many scenarios using java regex utility but it is failing in  below scenarios.

Below is the sample code I am using to match Text with HTML String

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "A crusader for the rights of the weaker sections of the Association&#39;s (ADA&#39;s),choice as the presidential candidate is being seen as a political masterstroke.";
    String regex = "A crusader for the rights of the weaker sections of the Association's (ADA's) ".replaceAll(" ", ".*");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    // Check all occurrences
    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
        System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
        System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());

    }
}
```

**Below the edge cases are getting failed**

**Case 1:**

**Source Text:** = `"A crusader for the rights of the weaker sections of the Association&#39;s (ADA&#39;s),choice as the presidential candidate is being seen as a political masterstroke."`;

**Text to match** = `"A crusader for the rights of the weaker sections of the Association's (ADA's)"`

**Expected output:** `“A crusader for the rights of the weaker sections of the Association&#39;s (ADA&#39;s)”`

**Case 2:**

**Source Text:**

```
“<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
see (<a href=\"https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/html-ipsum/">HTML Content Sample </a>.)
</ul>”
```

**Text to match:** `“see (HTML Content Sample.)”`

**Expected output:** `“see (<a href=\"https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/html-ipsum/">HTML Content Sample </a>.)”`

**Case 3:** 
**Source Text:**  = `"Initial history includes the following:</p>\n<p>Documentation  of <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>"`

**Text to match** = `"Initial history includes the following: Documentation of"`

**Expected output from matching:**`”Initial history includes the following :</p>\n<p>Documentation  of”`

Comment: first there are some characters is reserved in regex, for example the dot, the parenthesis `()` how you can deal with this?

Comment: I know this isn't very helpful but I wouldn't personally recommend RegEx for html manipulation for reasons here. There may also be some answers that help you if you absolutely have to use RegEx.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @YCF_L For parenthesis  () I am replacing with space

Comment: @YCF_L any Idea about above problem statement ?

Comment: mmm, this is not easy problem @pankajdesai because there are many cases you have to avoid not just the parenthesis but also the dot and other reserved character in regex :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently came up with a regular expression to match HTML tags, with support for quoted attributes and escaped quotes within quoted attributes: It goes like 
`<([^'">]|"([^\\"]|\\"?)+"|'([^\\']|\\'?)+')+>`.

I think the easiest way to search for plain text in HTML while preserving the HTML is to modify the plain text so that it ignores tags at word boundaries, à la

```java
// Usage: htmlSearch("ab cd").matcher("<b>ab</b> <i>cd</i>").matches();
public static Pattern htmlSearch(String plain) {
    // Check for tags before and after every word, number and symbol
    plain = plain.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+|\\d+|[^\\w\\s]", 
            "``TAGS``$0``TAGS``";
    // Check for tags wherever (one or more) spaces are found
    plain = plain.replaceAll("\\s+", "((\\s|&nbsp;)+|``TAGS``)*");
    // Handle special characters
    plain = plain
            .replace("<", "(<|&lt;|&#60;)")
            .replace(">", "(>|&gt;|&#62;)")
            .replace("&", "(&|&amp;|&#38;)")
            .replace("'", "('|&apos;|&#39;)")
            .replace("\"", "(\"|&quot;|&#34;)")
            .replaceAll("[()\\\\{}\\[\\].*+]", "\\$0");
    // Insert the ``TAGS`` pattern
    String tags = "(<([^'\">]"
                + "|\"([^\\\"]|\\\"?)+"
                + "|'([^\\']|\\'?)+')+>)*";
    plain = plain.replace("``TAGS``", tags);

    return Pattern.compile(plain);
}
```